# riverpod StateNorifierProvider is updating the value weirdly

Tags: flutter, riverpod

So, I am using Statenotifier to update my cartItem count also update the count in my firestore. when I first try to increment or decrement it works perfectly but when i try to decrement after incrementing or increment after decrementing i have to tap twice to update the counter but the firestore gets updated on first time. I don't know if I correctly described the problem but here is some code to clarifiy it.

```
cartItemCountNotifierProviderProvider -->
```

```
final cartItemCountNotifierProviderProvider =StateNotifierProvider.family<CartItemCountNotifier, int, int>((ref, int initalItemCount) {return CartItemCountNotifier(initalItemCount: initalItemCount);});
```

```
class CartItemCountNotifier extends StateNotifier<int> {CartItemCountNotifier({required int initalItemCount}): super(initalItemCount);
```

```
void incerementItemCount({required int quantity}) {if (state < quantity) {state++;}}
```

```
void decerementItemCount() {if (state > 1) {state--;}}
```

```
void setToDefault() {state = 1;}}
```

```
cartItemCount file -->
```

```
class CartItemCount extends ConsumerWidget {
  final ProductModel productModel;
  final CartModel cartModel;
  const CartItemCount({
    super.key,
    required this.productModel,
    required this.cartModel,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final cartItemCountProvider = ref.watch(
        cartItemCountNotifierProviderProvider(cartModel.itemCount).notifier);
    return Row(
      children: [
        GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              cartItemCountProvider.decerementItemCount();
              ref.watch(cartControllerProvider).decrementItemCountInFirebase(
                  cartItemId: cartModel.id, cartModel: cartModel);
            },
            child: const CircleAvatar(
              radius: 17,
              backgroundColor: Colors.black,
              child: CircleAvatar(
                radius: 15,
                backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                child: Icon(Icons.remove),
              ),
            )),
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
          child: Text(
            '${ref.read(cartItemCountNotifierProviderProvider(cartModel.itemCount))}',
            style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
          ),
        ),
        GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              cartItemCountProvider.incerementItemCount(
                  quantity: productModel.quantity);
              ref.watch(cartControllerProvider).incrementItemCountInFirebase(
                  cartItemId: cartModel.id, cartModel: cartModel);
            },
            child: const CircleAvatar(
              radius: 17,
              backgroundColor: Colors.black,
              child: CircleAvatar(
                radius: 15,
                backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                child: Icon(
                  Icons.add,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),
            )),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

```
cart repository file->

FutureVoid incrementItemCountInFirebase(
      {required String cartItemId,
      required String userId,
      required CartModel cartModel,
      required int itemCount}) async {
    try {
      final newCartModel = cartModel.copyWith(itemCount: itemCount);

      return right(await _firestore
          .collection('users')
          .doc(userId)
          .collection("cart")
          .doc(cartItemId)
          .update(newCartModel.toMap()));
    } on FirebaseException catch (e) {
      return left(Failure(e.toString()));
    }
  }

  FutureVoid decrementItemCountInFirebase(
      {required String cartItemId,
      required String userId,
      required CartModel cartModel,
      required int itemCount}) async {
    try {
      final newCartModel = cartModel.copyWith(itemCount: itemCount);

      return right(await _firestore
          .collection('users')
          .doc(userId)
          .collection("cart")
          .doc(cartItemId)
          .update(newCartModel.toMap()));
    } on FirebaseException catch (e) {
      return left(Failure(e.toString()));
    }
  }
```

}

```
  void decrementItemCountInFirebase({
    required String cartItemId,
    required CartModel cartModel,
  }) async {
    final cartitemCountProvider =
        _ref.watch(cartItemCountNotifierProviderProvider(cartModel.itemCount));
    _cartrepository.decrementItemCountInFirebase(
        itemCount: cartitemCountProvider,
        cartItemId: cartItemId,
        userId: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid,
        cartModel: cartModel);
  }
```

```
class CartItemTile extends ConsumerWidget {
  final ProductModel productModel;
  final CartModel cartModel;
  const CartItemTile({
    super.key,
    required this.cartModel,
    required this.productModel,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    return Row(
      children: [
        SizedBox(
          height: 100,
          width: 100,
          child: Image.network(
            productModel.images.first,
            height: 100,
            alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
            fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
          ),
        ),
        const Spacer(),
        Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Text(
              productModel.name,
              style: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 17),
            ),
            Text(productModel.brandName),
            Row(
              children: [
                Row(
                  children: [
                    Text('\$${productModel.discountedPrice}',
                        style: const TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          fontSize: 20,
                        )),
                    const SizedBox(width: 10),
                    if (productModel.discount > 0)
                      Text('\$${productModel.price}',
                          style: TextStyle(
                              decoration: productModel.discount > 0
                                  ? TextDecoration.lineThrough
                                  : TextDecoration.none,
                              decorationColor: Colors.red,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              fontSize: 17,
                              color: Colors.red)),
                  ],
                ),
                const SizedBox(width: 50),
                CartItemCount(productModel: productModel, cartModel: cartModel),
              ],
            )
          ],
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```